# Obtain background properties of element during css transition JQUERY

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element to which I add classes to with jquery in order to animate/carry out a CSS transition of the background property. The aim I have is to pause the transition while it's in motion, i thought maybe I could do this by obtaining the current background property of the element and then setting the css to those properties obtained.

HTML

```
  <div id="productimage">       
   </div>
```

CSS

```
#productimage {
    -webkit-transition: all 2.5s ease-out; -moz-transition: all 2.5s ease-out; -o-transition: all 2.5s ease-out;

}

#productimage.step2 {
    background-size:1500px 2275px;
    background-position: 30% 30%;
}

#productimage.step3 {
    background-image: url("../img/blusen-back.jpg");
    background-size:396px 600px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2.5s ease-out; -moz-transition: all 2.5s ease-out; -o-transition: all 2.5s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the property of the background, You can use:

```
element.css()
```

[Here is the link](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

And a JSFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9fbRV/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
    $('#giveMetheCurrentStyle').click(function() {
        var obj, matrix;
        obj = document.getElementById('circle');
        matrix = getComputedStyle(obj).getPropertyValue('transform');
        console.log(matrix);
        //$("#myDiv").css('transform', matrix)

        });
});
```

read more here http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-3d-transforms/